# What is the regex to find a non-digit (excluding periods)

Tags: regex

As this point in a code segment, i want to limit the text entered to only digits and periods.

I have everything working, but i wanted to shortcircut my code so that if it finds a NON DIGIT it will just return.  a PERIOD (.) is labelled as a non-digit.  Is there a way to just say something like  NON_DIGITS_LESS_PERIOD or something?

i was thinking

```
/\D[^\.]/
```

but that actually looks for a non digit followed by a non-period.

Thoughts on how to limit it as i am trying?

Comment: well the thing is, that it would be something like [^0-9.] because i wanted the periods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you actually want a NON_(DIGIT_OR_PERIOD):

```
/[^\d.]/
```

Btw, it might be easier to match against `/^[\d.]*$/`.

Comment: Just FYI, those wrapping slashes have nothing to do with regex

Comment: @Bohemian: They're a popular regex delimiter.

Comment: Exactly. Irrelevant to the question/answer, which us all about regex: The answer is `[^\d.]`.  The slashes are an application language artefact and have nothing to do with the answer. (I would remove them from an answer)

Comment: @Bohemian in the idea of regex, and javascript to create a regex, it would be something like:    var X = /[^\d.]/;  It is relevant to me, and is following the syntactic example i had given.  I say it is a valid answer.

Comment: Yeah, I could've omitted them. They serve two purposes: indicating that it's a regex in a cross-language manner (not necessary since it's clear here), and indicating that it's a whole regex and not only a part of an expression. I like that clarity.

Comment: Java and C#, two highly prominent languages, don't use slashes. I'm not down voting here, just saying that if someone using a language that doesn't use slashes searches and finds this question, the answer should relevant to them too. The question isn't tagged with a language - just "regex". Nuf said.