# regex any non-digit with exception

Tags: ruby, regex

I've got strings like these:

```
+996999966966AA
-996999966966AA
```

I am using this code:

```
"+996999966966AA".gsub!(/\D/, "")
```

to get rid of any character except digits, but the sign **+** also being stripped.  How can my code retain the **+**?

Comment: how about you do the reverse? `\+[0-9]+`

Comment: What is your language?

Comment: @Alma Do Mundo updated tag

Comment: Do you want to convert the result to an integer, too?

Comment: @Stefan, there's no need

Comment: Okay, otherwise you could simply use `"-996999966966AA".to_i`

Comment: You should also give us the code you have written for your problem,to understand why the code didn't work. SO doesn't welcome only problem statement in this case.

Comment: @Arup Rakshit, you had to read question properly, i said `...using \D to ...`

Comment: You want to retain `+`, but strip `-`?

Comment: There are several ways to use `\D`.. do you know that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the regex to find a non-digit (excluding periods)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780613/what-is-the-regex-to-find-a-non-digit-excluding-periods)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use:

```
[^+\d]
```

to match anything that isn't `+` or a digit.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `\W`, "non-word character" which matches any character that is not a word character (alphanumeric & underscore)).

```
(\W\d+)\w+
```

Comment: `\w` is `[A-Za-z0-9_]` so `\W` is anything not in that character set.